# How can i make first letter of all words in a string uppercase recursively?

Tags: c, function, recursion, c-strings, capitalize

I wonder how can i make this. I don't want any iteration or isalpha() and toupper() functions. We want to use our own code to read input. We assume that user enters all characters lowercase. This is what i've tried so far:

```
define MAX_LENGTH 100

int read_line(char str[],int);
void capitalize(char[]);

int main (void){
    char A[MAX_LENGTH];
printf("Enter a text \n");
read_line(A, MAX_LENGTH);

capitalize(A);
puts(A);


}

int read_line(char str[],int n){
    int ch,i=0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if(i<MAX_LENGTH)
            str[i++] = ch;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void capitalize(char str[]){
 int x = strlen(str);
 static int i = 0;
    if(str[i]=='\0')
    return;
    if(str[i-1]==' '|| i == 0)
      str[i] -= 32;
      i++;
      return capitalize(&str[i]);
 }
```

Output is like this:

> Enter a text:
>
> asdf sdf df
>
> Asdf sdf df

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `if(str[i-1]==' '|| i == 0)` is illegal when `i` is 0. Use `if(i == 0 || str[i-1]==' ')`

Comment: Using static in `static int i = 0;` lets you call it only one top-level time.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Just curious: Why recursive? Is it a part of an assignment? Otherwise, in C a linear recursion is almost always inferior to the loop constructs in terms of efficiency and in many cases also readability (particularly in _this_ case)

Comment: @Ctx to learn recursive function, obviously. Frankly, it is an "arbitrary" homework . If i don't it is not a problem but our exams are hard, like REALLY.

Comment: @whysoserious To learn recursive functions I would not use a special type like a linear, tail-recursive one. Go for binary trees or the like. Btw. your `read_line()` function can also be written "recursive"

Comment: @Ctx  i definitely consider your binary tree suggestion. I don't want to write read_line() recursive. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: @whysoserious I cite you: _I don't want any iteration_ Now what?

Comment: I don't want any iteration in capitalize function. Nobody understood this in the way:"I don't want any iteration at all" except you, sir. :) I am not a native speaker. Sorry for causing you to misunderstand :)

Comment: @whysoserious _Nobody understood this in the way_ How could you possibly know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is invalid. For example even the function read_line

```
int read_line(char str[],int n){
    int ch,i=0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if(i<MAX_LENGTH)
            str[i++] = ch;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

is incorrect at least because when `i` is equal to `MAX_LENGTH -1` there is an access memory beyond the character array

```
str[i] = '\0';
```

That is the condition of the loop is initially written incorrectly.

As for the recursive function then it can look for example the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_blank( char c )
{
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}

char * capitalize( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        int blank = is_blank( *s );

        if ( !blank )
        {
            *s &= ~' ';
        }

        capitalize( s + 1 );

        if ( !blank && !is_blank( *( s + 1 ) ) && *( s + 1 ) )
        {
            *( s + 1 ) |= ' ';
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "hello everybody. how do you do?";

    puts( s );
    puts( capitalize( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello everybody. how do you do?
Hello Everybody. How Do You Do?
```

Here is a similar demonstrative program but with your fixed function `read_line`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH  100

int is_blank( char c )
{
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}

char * capitalize( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        int blank = is_blank( *s );

        if ( !blank )
        {
            *s &= ~' ';
        }

        capitalize( s + 1 );

        if ( !blank && !is_blank( *( s + 1 ) ) && *( s + 1 ) )
        {
            *( s + 1 ) |= ' ';
        }
    }

    return s;
}

size_t read_line( char *s, size_t n )
{
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i + 1 < n && ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' )
    {
        s[i++] = ch;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[MAX_LENGTH];

    read_line( s, MAX_LENGTH );

    puts( s );

    puts( capitalize( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the string

```
hello everybody. how do you do?
```

then the program output will be the same as shown above.

```
hello everybody. how do you do?
Hello Everybody. How Do You Do?
```

If the bit-wise operations is unclear for you then you can substitute this statement

for this statement

```
*s &= ~' ';
```

for this statement

```
*s -= 'a' - 'A';
```

and this statement

```
*( s + 1 ) |= ' ';
```

for this statement

```
*( s + 1 ) += 'a' - 'A';
```

If to use your approach to the implementation of a recursive function with a static variable then it will be interesting to you why your function does not work will not be?

Let's consider it ignoring the first statement with the call of strlen.

```
void capitalize(char str[]){
 int x = strlen(str);
 static int i = 0;
    if(str[i]=='\0')
    return;
    if(str[i-1]==' '|| i == 0)
      str[i] -= 32;
      i++;
      return capitalize(&str[i]);
 }
```

First of all after the first call the function for one string you may not call it a second time for another string because the static variable `i` will not be already equal to 0.

The condition of the if statement should be written at least like

```
    if ( i == 0 || str[i-1]==' ' )
```

that is the order of sub-expressions shall be changed.

The return statement shall not contain an expression

```
      return capitalize(&str[i]);
```

you could just write

```
      capitalize(&str[i]);
```

Nevertheless the initial value of the pointer `str` was changed. However within the function you are using the index `i` relative the initial value of `str` of the first call of the function.

And I am sure it is interesting to you how correctly to rewrite the function, is not it?

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH  100

int is_blank( char c )
{
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}

char * capitalize( char *s )
{
    static size_t i = 0;

    if ( *( s + i ) )
    {
        if ( !is_blank( s[i] ) && ( i == 0  || is_blank( s[i-1] ) ) )
        {
            s[i] -= 'a' - 'A';
        }

        ++i;

        capitalize( s );

        --i;
    }

    return s;
}

size_t read_line( char *s, size_t n )
{
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i + 1 < n && ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' )
    {
        s[i++] = ch;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[MAX_LENGTH];

    read_line( s, MAX_LENGTH );

    puts( s );

    puts( capitalize( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be "that" guy but i am already overwhelmed by the fact i learnt too much throughout the way. I am trying to ask this without being annoying : Can you rewrite parts on this code so we don't use bitwise operators?

Comment: @whysoserious See my updated post.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much sir. i will search on size_t.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is that you're using index and recursion at the same time, simple recursive solution would be:

```
void capitalize(char* str, bool start){
    if (!*str) return; // end as soon as \0 is met
    if (start) 
        if (*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z') *str = (*str - 'a') + 'A'; // capitalize latin letters
    capitalize(str + 1, *str == ' '); // work with next symbol
}
```

should be called as `capitalize(str, true)`

Comment: Doesn't work. Function makes all letters uppercase.

Comment: So you want only te _first_ letter to be capitalized? You didn't say so.

Comment: @whysoserious do you want to capitalize all words or only first letter in each word?

Comment: First letter in each word.

Comment: @whysoserious ok, updated

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  i've edited it. I have an exhausting life sorry.

Comment: Can you eleborate it please? What is `start` variable?

Comment: @whysoserious start variable indicates whether current symbol can be considered as word start - it is either start of string or first letter after space

Comment: @Iłya Bursov There is no such a feature in C as default arguments.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow true, updated

Answer (score 0):

Should do the job:

```
void capitalize(char *s)
{
    while(1) {
        while (*s==' ') s++;                // skip spaces
        if (!*s) return;                    // check for end
        if ('a'<=*s && *s<='z') *s -= 32;   // capitalize if needed
        while (*s && *s!=' ') s++;          // advance
    }                                       // loop
}
```

(I call this "Stupid Character Processing")

Comment: In fact it is not a recursive function. It uses even two while loops. A recursive function shall not contain a loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, huh?? Since when may a recursive function not have loops? A recursive function only needs to call itself to be "recursive".

Comment: If you will write a function that does all the job in loops and only once calls itself to return the value calculated before may you call the function recursive? Recursion is always considered as an alternative for loops.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the following:

```
void capitalize(char* str) {
    if (! *str) return;      // job done
    *str = toupper(*str);    // capitalize "correctly"
    capitalize(++str);
}
```